# How to use Git cherry command in VSTS?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have 2 branches for a repo in VSTS. feature1 and master

[image]

I have a command line task to run git cherry command.

[image]

After running the build I am getting the following error in the command line task of Git.

[image]

Before building the `feature1` branch, I would like to check whether it has all the changes from `master` branch and to accomplish this I want to run git cherry command.

I have a hosted VSTS agent on a server under my organization. The screen looks like

[image]

Please let me know how to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you separate the tool (`git`) from the arguments (`cherry origin...`). after doing that I think you may still run into issues because VSTS performs a shallow fetch and puts you into a detached head state.This is due to performance and consistency.

Comment: I updated the arguments to put them into the arguments section, but as you said that didn't help. Is there any way in which I can achieve this?

Comment: You probably need todo the same trickery that is required to make GitVersion.exe work: https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/993

Comment: How come on my hosted agent it clearly says origin/master and origin/feature1 but doesn't recognize it over the VSTS command line task?

Comment: Check the logs, it deliberately detaches and checks out the hash. You're not meant to do funny stuff against the repo ;).

Comment: From my own log: 
`2017-09-13T11:26:12.9530541Z ##[command]git fetch --tags --prune --progress origin
2017-09-13T11:26:13.9076539Z ##[command]git checkout --progress --force ac4d55e22c9ccf72ab6fb4b72e783f06b8f38798`

Comment: The agent also removes the `origin` remote during the build and in the clean-up stage adds it back in: `2017-09-13T11:26:29.0955779Z ##[command]git remote set-url origin https://github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-tfvc-tasks.git
2017-09-13T11:26:29.1385556Z ##[command]git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-tfvc-tasks.git`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify arguments of git command in Arguments box, such as Tool: `git`; Arguments: `cherry origin/$(build.SourceBranchName) origin/master`.

[image]